# Force text in a div to break only after it reaches to the end of the div

Tags: html, css

In the code snippet below there are 2 examples to demonstrate what I am trying to accomplish:

I would like that my top example would behave like the one below, means it will stay in 2 lines with that given text, the problem is that when I use `space` it breaks the line and I would like the text to continue till the end of the div and only then to break.

Any css advice?

```css
  .myClass{
      font-size: 10px;
      color: #9a9a9a;
      width: 160px;
      overflow: hidden;
      -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
      word-wrap: break-word;  
    }
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="myClass">
      WWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    <div class="myClass">
      WWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWW WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following CSS for this

```
.myClass{
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #9a9a9a;
  width: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: @William can you share your code so I can figure out the problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h461dkej/
I found a way to achieve this : Put a zero-width joiner between each character ("&zwj;")